# How to append selected item to url in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am still fairly new to ruby on rails. I have a select tag and I want to append the selected value to a url. The select tag is set up like this:

```
<%= select_tag "locations", "<option value='union+grove+al'>Union 
Grove</option><option value='snow+point+rd+and+union+grove+rd'>Snow Point
Rd</option><option value='mobbs+school+rd'>Mobbs school
rd</option>".html_safe %>
```

I then have an iframe and would like to append the selected value to the url

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?q=[place selected value
here]&key=AIzaSyBC5sGcvCjFJgB0DZ1C-IYFyF2bnt4ym14"></iframe>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `select` tag would need to be encapsulated in a form, which, on submission would pass the selected value to the either a new page where the iFrame sits, or the same page if that is where it is.

The passed parameter could then be interpolated using

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?q=#<%=params[url]%>&key=AIzaSyBC5sGcvCjFJgB0DZ1C-IYFyF2bnt4ym14"></iframe>
```